# Is the United States I-134 immigration document legally binding?

Tags: contract-law, immigration

Is the I-134 immigration document legally binding?

It is supposedly an "affidavit of support" but it is not the I-864.  I have someone who is very hesitant to sign it but I am trying to explain that it is not legally binding.  However, I need the support to bring my fiancee to the USA.

Comment: I'm seeing references that you'll have to submit a I-864 when you apply to change your spouse's status. If you can't support an I-134 without a co-sponsor, what are you going to do for the I-864?

Comment: I can't comment yet I guess (not enough reputation), but for the I-864 you are allowed to use the alien (my fiancee)'s assets to meet the requirement. Likewise I actually intend to have a job that has the minimum income by the time we need to apply for that. So this is just for the I-134 to get my fiancee here to the US.

Comment: I am pretty sure you can always comment on your own questions regardless of reputation. It looks like you created a second account.

Comment: @Jimm, Matt is correct - it looks like you have created a second account. Please use the [contact](http://law.stackexchange.com/contact) link to request an account merge.

Answer (score 1):

The I-134 is not legally binding.

From the State Department's Foreign Affairs Manual, [9 FAM 302.8-2(B)(2)](https://fam.state.gov/fam/09FAM/09FAM030208.html#M302_8_2_B_2)(f)(3)(a):

> Nevertheless, there still are circumstances when Form I-134 will be
>   beneficial.  This affidavit, submitted by the applicant at your
>   request, is not legally binding on the sponsor and should not be
>   accorded the same weight as Form I-864.

From USCIS's Adjudicator's Field Manual, [Chapter 30.8](http://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/ilink/docView/AFM/HTML/AFM/0-0-0-1/0-0-0-12693/0-0-0-13496.html), the section on I-134s:

> Such affidavits, although helpful in judging financial ability, are
>   not legally binding.

[Here](https://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/USCOURTS-dcd-1_05-cv-01738/pdf/USCOURTS-dcd-1_05-cv-01738-0.pdf) is a federal district court opinion that confirms I-134 is not legally binding, and cites several legal precedents to support this (page 10-11):

> C. Affidavit of Support
>
> Zirintusa asserts that Whitaker breached the Affidavit of Support
>   (Form I-134) submitted to the INS, in which Whitaker promised to
>   provide room, board, and tuition to Zirintusa for a period of three
>   years.  Whitaker argues that the Affidavit of Support is not a binding
>   contract between the parties.  Federal Courts have repeatedly sided
>   with Whitaker.  *See, e.g., Cheshire v. Cheshire*, No.
>   3:05-CV-00453-TJC-MCR, 2006 WL 1208010, at *2 (M.D. Fla. May 4, 2006)
>   (“[F]ederal courts have consistently found that Form I-134 is not a
>   legally enforceable contract against a sponsor by a sponsored
>   immigrant.”); *Stump v. Stump*, No. 1:04-CV-253-TS, 2005 WL 1290658,
>   at *4 (N.D. Ind. May 27, Case 1:05-cv-01738-EGS   Document 39
>   Filed 01/03/07   Page 10 of 20 11 2005) (finding that the I-134 Form
>   “is a nonenforceable promise by the sponsor to support the alien”);
>   *Tornheim v. Kohn*, No. 00 CV 5084(SJ), 2002 WL 482534, at *4 (E.D.N.Y. Mar, 26, 2002) (“[A]n affidavit of support on an I-134 Form
>   is not a legally binding contract.”).  The Court sees no reason to
>   disagree with the holdings of these courts.  Thus, the Court grants
>   Whitaker’s motion for judgment on the pleadings as to Zirintusa’s
>   claim for breach of the Affidavit of Support.